# Como funciona esta sentencia preparada en PDO en PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy leyendo sobre PDO y sentencias preparadas, consegui esta forma de seleccionar datos de la base de datos, me gustaria que alguien me explicara porque no entiendo muy bien todas las funciones especialmente la clase declarada y el recursiveIterator Iterator, estoy acostumbrado a trabajar orientado a objetos o procedimientos:

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La declaración de la clase TableRows hereda de la clase RecursiveIteratorIterator y puedes hacer uso de los métodos públicos y protegidos.

Esto es útil para la definición y abstracción de la funcionalidad y permite la implementación de funcionalidad adicional en objetos similares sin la necesidad de reimplementar toda la funcionalidad compartida.

Claro que puedes sobreescribir algunos métodos en función de la lógica a implementar.

La clase RecursiveIteratorIterator, es la clase a partir de la cual heredas o sobre la cual creas una clase heredada o subclase.

Básicamente la clase Tablerows se crea a partir de la definición de la clase RecursiveIteratorIterator.

Aquí tienes más información:

http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php